# Should I Reset The ngrx State back to initial state on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm creating an angular application and created 3 simple crud operations. I've used ngrx for state management and it works nicely. I've subscribed to some slices of the states of each crud like

```
createUserLoaded$.subscribe(loaded => this.showSuccessNotification());
```

All is working good. I'm subscribing to these observables on **ngOnInit** of the respective component and unsubscribing all of them again on **ngOnDestroy**.

But the problem is, when I create a user, go to another route and come back to the **create user route** back, it shows me the success notification. The reason is last state of `createUserLoaded$` that was true and the respective component again subscribes to it.

So I wanted the opinion from the community that should I reset the reducer to its initial state again? Is it a good practice? or what else I should do?

Comment: if i read your question correctly...you should be using `async` pipe and forget about subscriptions to state. you pass your slices (which are observables) to your properties using `async` pipe and it does subscription management for you.

Comment: No its not like that. I'm already using async. The thing I'm asking is, resetting the reducer to its initialState is a good idea or bad if I come back to the component from another route

Comment: aha, ok now i see... i setup that kind of things like this: i have `CreateUserPending` and `CreateUserError` flags in state. When http request for creating user starts i set `CreateUserPending=true`. When the respond comes back i set `CreateUserPending=false` and result: if error then `CreateUserError=whateverErrorServerReturned` or if 200 OK just set actual created user slice (or just redirect somewhere else, depends on your ux logic). When i enter component, i list users and set errors to null but that highly depends on your ux workflow how and when you show what messages.

Answer (score 2):

Without code cant help you properly . but you can dispatch and event on ngOnDestroy() of your component to reset the state if you want to, also get in the habit of using async in your templates for your Observable they will do the unsubscribing for you. Ngrx goes hand and hand with the [Smart/Dumb Component](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-design-patterns-feature-and-presentation-components)

```
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new classAction.resetSuccessNotification());
 }
```

If your just using toasts to show notifications and don't care for their state then you can just use effects for that.loggerService is just a service to show toast

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
  createUserLoadede$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(Vendor.ActionType.CREATE_USER_LOADED),
    map((action: Vendor.createUserLoadedel) => action.payload),
    tap((payload) => this.loggerService.SuccessToast(payload.message, 6000))
  );
```

Comment: Thats what exactly I wanted to know but is it a good practice or should I use it?

Comment: The reducer can have logic to help format and automate some tasks in the state, you can even access the state in the effect and modify it if you must, this is not considered bad practice. In your case showing a notification you can create an Action to clear when dispatched or use a timer in an effect to show a toast and clear it after a certain time